# Autofac Multitenant Database Configuration

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, autofac, multi-tenant

I have a base abstract context which has a couple hundred shared objects, and then 2 "implementation" contexts which both inherit from the base and are designed to be used by different tenants in a .net core application.  A tenant object is injected into the constructor for OnConfiguring to pick up which connection string to use.

```
public abstract class BaseContext : DbContext
{
    protected readonly AppTenant Tenant;

    protected BaseContext (AppTenant tenant)
    {
        Tenant = tenant;
    }
}

public TenantOneContext : BaseContext
{
   public TenantOneContext(AppTenant tenant) 
        : base(tenant)
    {
    }
}
```

In startup.cs, I register the DbContexts like this:

```
services.AddDbContext<TenantOneContext>();
services.AddDbContext<TenantTwoContext>();
```

Then using the autofac container and th Multitenant package, I register tenant specific contexts like this:

```
IContainer container = builder.Build();

MultitenantContainer mtc = new MultitenantContainer(container.Resolve<ITenantIdentificationStrategy>(), container);

mtc.ConfigureTenant("1", config =>
{
    config.RegisterType<TenantOneContext>().AsSelf().As<BaseContext>();
});

mtc.ConfigureTenant("2", config =>
{
    config.RegisterType<TenantTwoContext>().AsSelf().As<BaseContext>();
});

Startup.ApplicationContainer = mtc;

return new AutofacServiceProvider(mtc);
```

My service layers are designed around the BaseContext being injected for reuse where possible, and then services which require specific functionality use the TenantContexts.

```
public BusinessService
{
   private readonly BaseContext _baseContext;

   public BusinessService(BaseContext context) 
   {
       _baseContext = context;
   }
}
```

In the above service at runtime, I get an exception "No constructors on type 'BaseContext' can be found with the constructor finder 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder'".  I'm not sure why this is broken....the AppTenant is definitely created as I can inject it other places successfully.  I can make it work if I add an extra registration:

```
builder.RegisterType<TenantOneContext>().AsSelf().As<BaseContext>();
```

I don't understand why the above registration is required for the tenant container registrations to work.  This seems broken to me; in structuremap (Saaskit) I was able to do this without adding an extra registration, and I assumed using the built in AddDbContext registrations would take care of creating a default registration for the containers to overwrite.  Am I missing something here or is this possibly a bug in the multitenat functionality of autofac?

**UPDATE:**

Here is fully runable repo of the question: https://github.com/danjohnso/testapp

Why is line 66 of Startup.cs needed if I have lines 53/54 and lines 82-90?

Comment: It is not clear from this explanation what are you doing when resolving this thing and which scopes are being created. Please create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, as it is outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `AddDbConetxt` (and the regular registration) utilizes the constructor which accepts `DbContextOptions`/`DbContextOptions<T>`. Did you tried to redeclare your constructor as `protected BaseContext (DbContextOptions options, AppTenant tenant) : base(options))`

Comment: @Tseng You can, but I needed to use OnConfiguring to override some other behavior in the context which is why I said I was using that.  alexander-leonov its not possible to break the whole application down into a runnable example.  I have provided and valid explanation of all the parts in play and the relevant code for someone who understands autofac well to provide me some guidance on this behavior

Comment: You can still do that iirc. `OnConfiguring` will  be called in any case, whether you construct it with the `DbContextOptions` constructor or not. You can use `IsConfigured` within `OnConfiguring` to find out if it has been configured via `DbContextOptions` or not. See the [remarks in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.onconfiguring?view=efcore-2.0)

Comment: @Tseng tried that, same result unless I triple register the Contexts

Comment: @AlexanderLeonov added repo

Comment: @Tseng see repo

Comment: @Dan - looking into it

Comment: @Dan - found the issue, will post my answer tonight. Repo actually helped a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I expected your problem has nothing to do with multitenancy as such. You've implemented it almost entirely correctly, and you're right, you do not need that additional registration, and, btw, these two (below) too because you register them in tenant's scopes a bit later:

```
        services.AddDbContext<TenantOneContext>();
        services.AddDbContext<TenantTwoContext>();
```

So, you've made only one very small but very important mistake in `TenantIdentitifcationStrategy` implementation. Let's walk through how you create container - this is mainly for other people who may run into this problem as well. I'll mention only relevant parts.

First, `TenantIdentitifcationStrategy` gets registered in a container along with other stuff. Since there's no explicit specification of lifetime scope it is registered as `InstancePerDependency()` by default - but that does not really matter as you'll see. Next, "standard" IContainer gets created by autofac's `buider.Build()`. Next step in this process is to create `MultitenantContainer`, which takes an instance of `ITenantIdentitifcationStrategy`. This means that `MultitenantContainer` and its captive dependency - `ITenantIdentitifcationStrategy` - **will be singletons** regardless of how `ITenantIdentitifcationStrategy` is registered in container. In your case it gets resolved from that standard "root" container in order to manage its dependencies - well, this is what autofac is for anyways. Everything is fine with this approach in general, but this is where your problem actually begins. When autofac resolves this instance it does exactly what it is expected to do - injects all the dependencies into `TenantIdentitifcationStrategy`'s constructor including `IHttpContextAccessor`. So, right there in the constructor you grab an instance of `IHttpContext` from that context accessor and store it for using in tenant resolution process - **and this is a fatal mistake: there's no http request at this time, and since `TenantIdentitifcationStrategy` is a singleton it means that there will not ever be one for it!** So, it gets `null` request context for the whole application lifespan. This effectively means that `TenantIdentitifcationStrategy` will not be able to resolve tenant identifier based on http requests - because it does not actually analyze them. Consequently, `MultitenantContainer` will not be able to resolve any tenant-specific services.

Now when the problem is clear, its solution is obvious and trivial - just move fetching of request context `context = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext` to `TryIdentifyTenant()` method. It gets called in the proper context and will be able to access request context and analyze it.

PS. This digging has been highly educational for me since I had absolutely no idea about autofac's multi-tenant concept, so thank you very much for such an interesting question! :)

PPS. And one more thing: this question is just a perfect example of how important well prepared example is. You provided very good example. Without it no one would be able to figure out what the problem is since the most important part of it was not presented in the question - and sometimes you just don't know where this part actually is...

Comment: Good find!  Yes, I should have tried to do a full repo up front but was hoping there was something easy to it I was missing from documentation as it took me a while to extract everything to a minimum.  So super fun follow up, if you try to run the exact same code in full IIS instead of IIS Express, autofac gives the same error about not being able to find the BaseContext.  I'm just starting to dig and try to figure out why, but if you have any thoughts @AlexanderLeonov let me know

Comment: @Dan - we never tried to host our .net core project on iis, we're hosting it on linux using kestrel with apache in front of it, so, most likely I'll not be able to help you with that. Besides, no one in our team likes IIS. :) But I'd expect something similar - just some tiny small detail or setting that is not even related to your multitenancy thing but still screws up everything. :)